# Inject dependencies into Doctrine2 Model via Silex/Pimple

Tags: php, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, silex

is there any way to inject dependencies into Doctrine2 models with Silex? Since the models are not constructed manually i can't pass anything to the constructor and i can't find a tutorial how to do it. I already browsed the source of Silex and Pimple and i didn't got how this could be archived.  Any help appreciated.

Nils

Update:
Models are newable not injectable so you need to inject dependencies via setters after construction.
doctrine2 implements this feature out of the box, so here is a link to the documentation:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/events.html

Comment: Kind of duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295588/doctrine-2-with-symfony-di-container :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silex doesn't have built-in service provider for Doctrine 2 ORM, but you can use this [extension](https://github.com/mjakubowski/nutwerk-orm-extension).
I posted on my blog a short tutorial [how to implement it to Silex](http://martinsikora.com/silex-doctrine2-orm).

Comment: haha, thanks dude....i just came back to update this question with your blog post. Somehow you are in my RSS reader, but i guess it's because it got featured on phpdev or some other big site. ;)

Answer (score -1):

> There is only a Doctrine DBAL. An ORM service is not supplied.

source: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html

Did you create your own service for doctrine ORM?

Comment: kind of...i tweaked the one of docteurklein a little bit.